Use CSS to show which div will receive pasted text
I have 2 divs which can receive pasted text. They are not editable. How can I visually indicate which one will receive the paste event?
I tried using :focus, but it does nothing by default for divs. I added tabindex to the div, and then :focus worked, but if I click outside the div, it losses the focus attribute but still receives the pasted text


document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener("paste", event => {
                event.preventDefault();
                const text = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text");
                const words = text.split(' ').join('\n');
                event.currentTarget.innerText = words;
            }
            )
        });
<div>aaa</div>
<div>bbb</div>




I would suggest adding a border or changing its color.

@mykaf that is what I want to do. The question is how do I do that?

Have you tried anything? I'd start by using your favorite search engine to find "How to add a border to a div with javascript"

@mykaf Yes, I did, as I explained in the question. I know how to add a border. I don't know how to add the border only to the element that is going to receive the current paste event

You didn't explain in the question anything about borders. However, you seem to know how to get the div that's receiving the event, and you know how to add a border. Put those two together.

@mykaf No, I don't know how to get the div until the event is triggered. I want to show which div will get the event if the user pastes something now.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Is a JS solution viable? You could check which node has the current selection (through getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer), but I don't think there is any CSS selector for that right now.

I can’t see anything in the question which tells what the next div to receive the paste will be. How is that determined? Is there an assumption, taking the example code given, that before any pasting has been done then the first div (which starts by having aaa inside it) will take the paste, then the next paste will go into the div which initially had bbb in it? Then what happens?

@AHaworth it is determined by the browser. I don't know the all the ways it can change. I do know that clicking on a div makes it the next one to get the paste, but there may be other ways

The paste event is fired on the Selection's range's startContainer (though it's ill-specced currently, see this issue).
There is currently no CSS selector that allows us to target this node in particular1. So you'll need to resort to JS.
You can do so by listening to the document's selectionchange event and set a class or attribute to mark the current element holding this node.


document.addEventListener("selectionchange", (evt) => {
  for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll(".selected-node")) {
    elem.classList.remove("selected-node");
  }
  const selection = getSelection();
  const range = selection.rangeCount && selection.getRangeAt(0);
  const anchorNode = range?.startContainer;
  const anchorElement = anchorNode?.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE
    ? anchorNode
    : anchorNode.parentElement;
  anchorElement.classList.add("selected-node");  
});
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("paste", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text");
    const words = text.split(' ').join('\n');
    event.currentTarget.innerText = words;
  });
});
div:has(.selected-node),div.selected-node {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
<div>aaa</div>
<div>bbb</div>



1. The ::selection pseudo-element came close but it unfortunately doesn't seem to work with :has(), because it could create a cycle, e.g. with display:none.

Take a look at this and see if it might help you.
You can only paste text if a div is focused.
If no div is selected, the text will not be pasted.
The div that is focused on will be highlighted with a distinct border.


// Track the currently focused div
let currentTarget = null;

document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(element => {
  // Add a click event to indicate focus
  element.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent global click handler from interfering
    if (currentTarget) {
      currentTarget.classList.remove("focused");
    }
    currentTarget = element;
    currentTarget.classList.add("focused");
  });

  // Handle paste event
  element.addEventListener("paste", event => {
    if (currentTarget === element) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const text = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text");
      const words = text.split(' ').join('\n');
      element.innerText = words;
    }
  });
});

// Global click handler to clear focus if clicking outside
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (currentTarget) {
    currentTarget.classList.remove("focused");
    currentTarget = null;
  }
});
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div:hover {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
div.focused {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
<div>aaa</div>
<div>bbb</div>




You can't get focused on DIV elements out of "onpaste" event listener. You have to create a null or hidden div "lastHiddenDIV" and add it to "onpaste" event listener but prevent it from updating it's innerHTML using IF statement.
and put them in a DIV as parent with CSS=overflow:hidden;


let pastingEL = document.querySelectorAll(".pasting");
document.querySelectorAll(".pasting").forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("paste", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text");
    const words = text.split(' ').join('\n');
    if (event.currentTarget != pastingEL[pastingEL.length - 1]) {
      event.currentTarget.innerText = words;
    }
  })
});
<div style="border:1px solid blue; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="pasting">aaa</div>
  <div class="pasting">bbb</div>
  <div class="pasting" style="width:100%; height:100%;">lastHiddenDIV</div>
</div>




You could simply add a border to the div to make it obvious. If you have a dedicated CSS file:
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:grey;

You can play around with the color/thickness of the border but you probably want something a little more subtle.
Inline:
<div style="border: 1px solid grey"></div>

You will need to set the style dynamically when the element is selected.

The issue is not which style to use, the issue is how to determine which div is the target of the next paste.
